# Two features at one branch, how to avoid lost of work if need to undo one feature

Tags: git, checkout

I was working on `Feature-1` branch , some changes not being commit; Suddenly I need to work on another task that is related to Feature 2 but I didn't get the chance to swtich or create a new branch for this.  So new changes for two features exsisting at the same time in one feature branch (i.e. Feature-1).

Then I `checkout -b` to a new branch name :`Feature-2` from `Feature-1` to make sure the new changes relates to `Feature-2` is coming along. But I need to undo the changes that relates to `Feature 1` in this new branch which leads to the lost of my previous changes in regards to Feature 1.

What is the proper workflow should I follow in this scenerio?

Comment: Does `Feature-2` depend on `Feature-1` or are they independent?

Comment: they belong to the same project, but independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two features are independent, you should `stash` your changes for `Feature-1` before starting work on `Feature-2`.

---

Assuming you are currently on branch `Feature-1` and you have uncommitted changes:

1. `git stash -u` - Save your current set of changes to the stash. `-u` makes it include untracked files.
2. Do whatever you need to do. Switch branches, make new branches, make new commits, whatever.
3. Switch back to branch `Feature-1`
4. `git stash pop` - Reapply the most recent changes from the stash

Answer (score 0):

`git revert -n` the commit(s) whose effects you don't want.

Comment: I have nothing commit yet,I think this is the issue that I need to commit before checkout.  when I do checkout -b it carrys the the uncommit changes to new branch.